# Core Data string value to NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've fetched what I want from my core data:

NSArray *result

How can I add those string values from result to another NSArray?

Comment: Can you add more details and maybe some source code?

Comment: Do you mean how to add values from an array to another? If so, simply `[NSMutableArray addObjectsFromArray:result]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **copy** method of `NSArray` as below example:

```
EX: NSArray *result=[context executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];
    NSArray *anotherArray = [result copy];
```

or If you want to pass object to NSMutableArray then  use as :

```
NSMutableArray *anothrMutableArray = [result mutableCopy];
```

Comment: NSArray *result=[context executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];

this is my array from fetching data from my core data database
assume I don't know how many results at first place, How I need to do to achieve something like you just advised?
Thank you.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Check it out.

Comment: It's probably better to write `NSMutableArray *anotherMutableArray = [result mutableCopy];` for the last example.

Comment: Ya right. I have updated.